# How to get information about a bag without downlaoding the whole thing

Tags: rosbag

I have a bunch of huge bags stored in the cloud and I am trying to build a database of all the data. I want to try to gather information about this bags, like the date, which topics it has, etc., by downloading the least possible amount of the bag to accelerate the process. I thought rosbag had some kind of header that would be read by commands like "rosbag info" but I couldn't really figure it out.
Does anyone have any hints or experience with it?